# React: Don't use keyUp for onChange events

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs, keyup

Is it possible to have React fire the `onChange` event after the focus on an element is lost as opposed to having it on `keyUp` (currently, `onChange` is an abstraction of any event that manipulates the field value)? `keyUp` is a little slow for me, and I think it may help the mobile expereince with what I'm building to switch the firing of that to after the field is focused.

Comment: Isn't this normally what the 'onBlur' event is for? I'm unfamiliar with the React framework, but I imagine it might support that in some form.

Comment: Sure is. React abstracts events though, it's one of those huge view frameworks

Answer (score 6):

Are you looking for something like this?

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4TpnG/205/)

I may be interpreting what you're asking for incorrectly, but you should be able to get your values via  e.target.value or through using a ref, like:

```
<input type="text" ref="myValue" onBlur={this.handleChange} />
```

and then in your handleChange function you'd have something like this:

```
handleChange: function()
{
    var theValue = this.refs.myValue.getDOMNode().value;
    //setState, etc. here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could build your own component that support this behavior, for example:

```
var ChangeOnBlurInput = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var options = this.props;
    options.onBlur = options.onChange;
    // You can also use `transferPropsTo` here, but I've heard it's deprecated
    return React.DOM.input.call(React.DOM, options);
  }
});

React.renderComponent(
  ChangeOnBlurInput({
    value: "Nice", 
    onChange: function(e) { alert(e.target.value) } }),
 document.body);
```

And use it instead of `React.DOM.input` wherever you want.